# Spring security redirect after success is not respecting the context-path from x-forwarded-prefix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am running Spring cloud security behind Spring cloud gateway.

I have setup my project to use `forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE`.

Everything works as expected except, after a successful login, the redirect ignores the original 'x-forwarded-for' headers.

e.g.
I have this route to my auth server:

```
         -  id: xxxx
            uri: xxxxx
            predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
            filters:
            - RewritePath=/auth(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
         -  id: yyyy
            uri: xxxxx
            predicates:
            - Path=/oauth2/**, /login/**, /login, /logout
```

1. I call /auth/a-page
2. Call gets redirected to /login
3. OAuth Login dance happens successfully
4. Redirect is sent for /a-page instead of /auth/a-page

NB: Both routes point to the same Spring JVM
Update: req.getContextPath() correctly returns /auth

It this a bug or am I missing something?
Should I create a custom redirect handler?

Comment: I only see `/auth` in your config, where does `/user` come into play? If the redirect is coming from your downstream service (behind the gateway), I believe you will need to rewrite the `Location` header that comes back through the gateway to prepend `/auth`. I'm not sure what `forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE` does.

Comment: That was a typo... :) I updated it